# what is the "s or s[0] in Yy " in the following code convert to?

Tags: python-3.x

In the following code that uses python, the  `def __sub__()` and  `def __eq__()` are or aren't being used? I'm use to seeing these as `variableObject.action` like in say `my_dog.sit()`. However, with the double underscore, it seems inherent by simply calling the `class Point3D()`, which is probably being used in `def is_win()`.

I also am having difficulty reading this particular  `while not s or s[0] in Yy`  as its [0] would seem to indicate a simply enter to exit and not enter the loop. Further, I am at a loss on how the `Yy` is being used here.

I've tried entering `s[1]` and it says index is out of range, confirming the enter to exit. Shouldn't it simply read `while not s[0]` for a cleaner code?

```py
    class Point3D:
             '''Three dimensional point class, supporting
                subtraction and comparison. '''

         def __init__(self, x, y, z):
              self.x = x
              self.y = y
              self.z = z

         def __sub__(self, other):
              d1 = self.x - other.x
              d2 = self.y - other.y
              d3 = self.z - other.z
              return Point3D(d1, d2, d3)

         def __eq__(self, other):
              return(self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
                     and self.z == other.z)

    def main():
         s = ''
         while not s or s[0] in 'Yy':
              p1 = get_point()
              p2 = get_point()
              p3 = get_point()
              if is_win(p1,p2,p3):
                   print('is a winning combination.')
              else:
                   print('Is not a win.')
              s = input('Do again(Y or N)?')
    def get_point():
         s = input('Enter point x, y, z format:')
         ls = s.split(',')
         x, y, z = int(ls[0]), int(ls[1]), int(ls[2])
         return Point3D(x,y,z)

    def is_win(p1,p2,p3):
         if(p3-p2 == p2 - p1
     or p2-p3 == p3-p1
     or p3-p1 == p1-p2):
          return True
     else:
          return False
main()
```

Comment: __sub__ is an internal method of all objects that Python uses when instances of the class are subtracted. Here it is given a custom function in order to make sense when subtracting Point3D objects, as happens in the `is_win()` method. __eq__ is similarly used when objects are being compared to see if they are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `__sub__` and `__eq__` are "special" methods in python classes. Whenever you compare two objects of the same class you use one of `__eq__`, `__gt__`, or `__lt__`. `__eq__` is nothing but `==`. So when you do `p1 == p2` use use the `__eq__` method. In the same vein, `__sub__` is for subtraction. When you do `p1 - p2` you use `__sub__`. **You don't use these the same way you would use other methods**. You *dont* `p1.__sub__(p2)`.

The second part is you're waiting for `s` to be `y` *or* `Y`.